# Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in, because of mysql query

Tags: php, android, mysql

When in android programming i am using jsonarray when i type simple query it works but hen i type query in php function it returns error:

Php Code:

```
session_start();

  $friendlocs=$db->getFriendsLocations($_SESSION['email']);


 $a=array();
 $b=array();

if ($res){
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($friendlocs))
    {
            //$b["id"] = $data[$j]->id;

            $b["f_name"] = $row[0];
            $b["f_email"] = $row[0];
            $b["f_lat"] = $row[1];
            $b["f_lon"] = $row[2];
            $b["f_time"] = $row[3];
            $b["f_timezone"] = $row[4];
            $b["f_synctime"] = $row[5];
            $b["f_friend_status"] = $row[6];



            array_push($a,$b);

    }
}



echo json_encode($a);
```

Php function and query:

```
        public function getFriendsLocations($user_email) {

// THIS QUERY RETURNS ERROR BUT IF I RUN THIS QUERY IN MYSQL EDITOR, IT WORKS       
$result = mysql_query("select user_email,and_loc_lat, and_loc_long, and_loc_time, and_loc_timezone, and_sync_time, user_loc_status FROM tbl_currentlocs WHERE user_email = ANY (select DISTINCT friend_email FROM tbl_friendship WHERE user_email = '$user_email')");

//IF I USE result2 query it works on php and JSON

  $result2 = mysql_query("select user_email,and_loc_lat, and_loc_long, and_loc_time, and_loc_timezone, and_sync_time, user_loc_status FROM tbl_currentlocs");  // WHERE user_email = '$user_email'


        return $result;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your while loop try var_dump($row) and post your output here

Comment: When i changed php function code it works:

Answer (score 0):

When i changed php function code it works. I think some sql syntax cannot work. When i type the query above and the new query both returns same values from mysql SQL editor, but when i use sql query above with IN and ANY words it does not work on php function to json code.

here is my new query:

```
    public function getFriendsLocations($user_email) {

        $result = mysql_query("select t1.user_email,t1.and_loc_lat, t1.and_loc_long, t1.and_loc_time, t1.and_loc_timezone, t1.and_sync_time, t1.user_loc_status FROM tbl_currentlocs t1 INNER JOIN tbl_friendship t2 ON t1.user_email=t2.friend_email AND t2.user_email='$user_email'");


        return $result;

}
```